# Docker container issue

Tags: spring-boot, docker, gradle

I am using gradle to build my spring boot application.It will create a jar file in build/libs

My Docker file is

```
     From openjdk:8-jre-alpine
     VOLUME /temp
     COPY build/libs /app
     ENTRYPOINT["java","-jar","/app/colltor.0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
     EXPOSE 8080:8080
```

I am able to build image successfully.But when i try to run container using that image i get below error

```
  docker run image-id
  Error Unable to access jarfile /app/colltor.0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Comment: You might want to run a `ls -lR` to see where your jar really is. I wouldn't expect it in lib.

Comment: @Marged jar is in lib i can see Its there and that .jar has rw-r--r-- permissions.I manually changed the permission to 777 still the same issue.

Comment: After your image is built do a `docker run -it image-id bash` this will let you explore your image and see what the problem is. 
I would suggest going into /app and seeing what in there and what the jar file is called

Comment: Where did you change the file permissions? Inside the container?

Comment: @AElMehdi i have tried to change permission in build/libs and then creatd image from Dockerfile.But still the same issue.

Comment: I tried docker run -it image-id bash but still same error "Error Unable to access jarfile /app/colltor.0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"

Comment: The thing is you need to verify within your container if you have the right permissions on that file (use the command suggested by @Todoy)